# SPIN representation to SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, semantic-web, spin-rdf

Is there an API that could help convert SPIN representation (of a SPARQL query) back to its SPARQL query form?

From:

```
[ a                              <http://spinrdf.org/sp#Select> ;
  <http://spinrdf.org/sp#where>  ( [ <http://spinrdf.org/sp#object>  [ <http://spinrdf.org/sp#varName>
                                                       "o"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ] ;
                                     <http://spinrdf.org/sp#predicate>
                                             [ <http://spinrdf.org/sp#varName>
                                                       "p"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ] ;
                                     <http://spinrdf.org/sp#subject>
                                             [ <http://spinrdf.org/sp#varName>
                                                       "s"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> ]
                                   ] )
] .
```

To:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when I use a common search engine, the first hit is https://github.com/spinrdf/spinrdf - does it not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I know two jena-based APIs to work with SPIN.

You can use either `org.topbraid:shacl:1.0.1` which is based on `jena-arq:3.0.4` or the mentioned in the comment `org.spinrdf:spinrdf:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, which is a fork of the first one, but with changed namespaces and updated dependencies.

Note the first (original) API also may work with modern jena (3.13.x), at least your task can be solved in such circumstances.
The second API has no maven release yet, but can be included into your project via jitpack.

To solve the problem you need to find the root `org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource` and cast it to `org.topbraid.spin.model.Select` (or `org.spinrdf.model.Select`) using jena polymorphism (i.e. the operation `org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode#as(Class)`).
Then `#toString()` will return the desired query with the model's prefixes.
Note that all personalities are already included into model via static initialization.

A demonstration of this approach is [SpinTransformer](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/owlcs/ontapi/utils/SpinTransform.java) from ONT-API test-scope, which transforms SPARQL-based queries to an equivalent form with `sp:text`.